# Colour-based raster vectorizing in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, vector

Following the query;

[Cannot extract the WMS tiles to arbitrary GIS format](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/397072/cannot-extract-the-wms-tiles-to-arbitrary-gis-format)

where I asked about a possibility to get the WMS layer to QGIS or get the layer in some versatile vector GIS format.

Now I would like to ask about the possibility of vectorizing the raster map by color.

[image]

As you can see, I have the infrastructure, which is entirely black. It's distinguished well from the map canvas underneath.

Is it possible to vectorize only these layers at some point? Make the colored vectorization? I want only the structure, but I don't need the map at all.

Something analog to **"Trace Bitmap"** tool in Inkscape?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E7HwLTQu2FI&ab_channel=TJFREE

Comment: Screenshot everything, merge the images, then use the raster calculator to create a mask, then convert the mask to vector data. And no, the data wont look great.

Comment: What do you mean by "screenshot everything?" and how to make the mask in QGIS?

Comment: Screenshot the whole area of interest, or rather export it to georeferenced images.

Comment: you know there is a Vector Tile Service (VTS) for that data right? https://osdatahub.os.uk/docs/vts/technicalSpecification

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had some fun with your image:

1. Use raster calculator to recalculate the image to 1 or 0:

`(("xSTNz@1"+"xSTNz@2"+"xSTNz@3")<75)*1 + (("xSTNz@1"+"xSTNz@2"+"xSTNz@3")>74)*0`
Where sum of the bands are below 75 (almost black) give them the value 1, else 0
[image]
[image]

2. Use Warp to set no data value to 0:
   [image]
3. Raster pixels to polygons, only the no no-data (1) gets vectorized:

[image]

Still very raw data, but in vector format. I would then try Dissolve, find centerline etc...